# How to retrieve Instagram comments that contain a hashtag?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

With Instagram's API, you can search for photos/videos that contain a certain hashtag.

Is it possible to find comments that contain a certain hashtag? The use case is finding photos that have a comment with `#ahashtag` even though the photo itself does not have `#ahashtag` on the caption.

For that matter, can you even search this way within the iOS or Android app?

I have tried the `tags/media/recent` which only returns photos that have the hashtag in their own caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Only photos in which the owner added the hashtag will be available in a search for said hashtag. That is, if I add a hashtag in a comment on your photo, your photo won't show up in a search for that tag. It does not matter if the hashtag is in the caption or if the owner added it to a later comment, it behaves the same way.